# É possível usar ponteiros em VB.NET?

Tags: c++, vb.net, ponteiro

É possível usar ponteiros em VB.NET? Se sim, como funcionam?

Um exemplo em `C++`:

```
CSR = ConfigurarInterfaceDeRede(randInt(0,999999),CodAtivacaoSAT,(char*)xml);

int  a;
int *p;
p = &a;
```

Como traduziria isto para `VB.NET`?

Comment: Ola. E possível (existe algo parecido com ponteiros na forma da estrutura InPtr). A questão mais importante, porque? Para que precisa de ponteiros? De algum contexto para poder responder melhor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não, diretamente não pode.

## Alternativa

O máximo que você consegue usar é o [`IntPtr`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1) disponível no .NET. É uma forma mais limitada, ainda que permita uma referência para um ponto da memória ser criada em VB.NET. Internamente ele é representado como um `void *`, mas no fundo é apenas um `Integer` para o VB.NET.

Não é possível desreferenciá-lo (até dá com a classe [`InteropServices.Marshal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1)) ou fazer aritmética direta com o ponteiro (indiretamente dá). Em alguns casos o uso de [`GCHandle`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1) também pode ser útil

## Pra que ponteiros?

O mais importante é que em geral você não precisa de ponteiros na linguagem. A ideia do VB.Net é outra, é facilitar sua vida e não trazer complicações. A maneira como a linguagem foi construída é possível fazer tudo o que normalmente faria com ponteiros sem usá-los.

A maioria das construções necessárias podem ser obtidas de outras formas de mais alto nível, com mais abstração.

É claro que isto pode não ser o mais performático possível, mas resolve o problema e esta é a filosofia do VB.NET. Se precisar de performance mesmo, faça apenas o que é realmente necessário para performance em outra linguagem e integre com seu programa em VB.NET (essa integração é simples em linguagem que rodam em cima do CLR). Se você saber usar ponteiros, saberá usar outra linguagem.

## Ponteiros são opacos

Entenda que existem ponteiros na plataforma, só não estão visíveis para a linguagem. Quando você usa uma classe, você certamente está usando ponteiros, mas não os vê. Quando usa *delegates* ou *lambdas*, está usando ponteiro, até porque são classes também. Só não está os vendo. Ao invés de usar um `char *` você usa a classe `String` (elas não são completamente compatíveis mas atendem o mesmo propósito, um *array* de `byte`s está mais próximo do que é um `char *`).

Quando precisa passar um argumento que não é uma referência (classes por exemplo) por referência usa-se o `ByRef` no parâmetro, então não precisa de ponteiro.

```vb
Sub Main()
   Dim y As Integer
   Test(y)
End Sub

Sub Test(ByRef x As Integer)
    x = 42
nd Sub
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Reference.vb).

Algumas classes possuem métodos próprios que ajudam fazer determinadas operações que normalmente demandariam um ponteiro.

## Quando o ponteiro realmente é necessário.

Seja para dar poder, seja para dar flexibilidade ou seja para dar velocidade, há casos que o ponteiro é necessário.

Nestes casos você deve recorrer à outras linguagens suportadas na CLR. O .NET faz isto na sua implementação interna. Note que ele foi desenvolvido com C# por esta ser uma linguagem mais poderosa. nela é possível usar ponteiros de forma limitada através de [blocos `unsafe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Também pode usar ponteiros em C++ de forma bastante abrangente mas ainda gerenciado pelo *garbage collector* do .NET. Normalmente isto é feito mais em casos de interoperabilidade e em casos extremos de necessidade de velocidade.

De fato é possível usar linguagens fora do CLR. A implementação do .NET faz isto o tempo todo. Ele chama as APIs do Windows escritos em C de forma nada gerenciada. Quando que o controle total, inclusive da memória, esta pode ser a solução.

Para interoperabilidade dá para resolver com as classes passadas acima e alguns atributos extras. Você terá que aprender todos os aspectos para *marshalizar* o acesso.

Comment: Entendi, estou estudando isso ainda, pq preciso conversar com um equipamento que no caso as funções e variáveis de exemplo estão em C++ e usam esses métodos de return pointer, em algumas funções.
Então vou tentar fazer sem usar os ponteiros.
Obrigado!!!

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Bigown!
Está me ajudando muito esses exemplos e essa explicação clara.
Obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Se você tiver alguma dúvida para fazer a interoperabilidade do VB.Net com C ou C++, você pode fazer outra pergunta específica sobre isto. Eu nunca fiz nada com isto mas é possível que outras pessoas tenham feito.

Comment: Tudo bem, irei fazer assim que surgir.
Mas mesmo não ter feito nada vc me ajudou muito,rsrs
Obrigado por ora, forte abraço!